# Input and output impedance matching for the HMC414 amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance, impedance-matching, microwave, power-amplifier

I have a question about the impedance matching at the input and output of the HMC414 power amplifier. I don't know exactly where to put this matching, and I wouldn't want to make a mistake. The amplifier schematic looks as follows (taken from the data sheet from this link: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc414.pdf ):

[image]

I put it there (take into account that DEA142450BT-3028A1 is a bandpass filter), does it make any sense? I would appreciate any comment or response:

[image]

Additionally, the data sheet shows the layout whether the input and output impedance matching should be on the transmission line, respectively - input at J1 and output at J2 (J1 and J2 are PCB Mount SMA RF Connector):

[image]

Comment: The matching is for the amplifier, put it as shown on the amplifier output, the length of line between C1, C2 and L1 is part of the matching circuit, shown as TL1/2/3 on the top diagram. You may need to diplex-filter the input to the bandpass filter to make it a broadband match to the amplifier. Putting a nasty load on the output of the amplifier could cause instability

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for your comment. I understand then that I should put the impedance matching between the line between C1, C2 and L1, yes? What about the impedance matching at the input? Should I leave it or is it redundant. 

From the simulation done in the AWR program, the amplifier shows that it is conditionally stable.

Comment: And most importantly - did I understand correctly that my approach (diagram with IN and OUT circles marked) is at least somewhat good? And is it just that the output matching should be before the filter?

Comment: The amplifier matching **is** C1/L1/TL1/2. Where did you get the idea for your shunt L components as matching? Link to the publication that suggested those.

Comment: The problem with the filter is that the return loss is a respectable -20dB from 2.3 to 2.6 GHz, but below 2.2 GHz it goes to - 10dB and to 0db(ish) by 2 GHz. If you look at the S-parameters of the HMC414, it also has a horrible S22 and bags of gain at 2 GHz, so the pair of them are going to go off unless you diplex that filter to tidy up its return loss.